# Struts 2 Jquery Plugin require internet connection

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am working on struts 2 web application which uses struts2-jquery-plugin-3.1.0.jar for UI. The application is deployed on tomcat, server starts fine if internet connection is enabled, however if the server is behind firewall or internet connection is diabled, the following exception is thrown while starting the server.

```
- Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Jul 27, 2011 11:14:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: Unable to load jar:file:/D:/workspace_helios/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/myapplication/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.1.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:890)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:144)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: struts.apache.org - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:885)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
    ... 27 more
Jul 27, 2011 11:14:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jul 27, 2011 11:14:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/myapplication] startup failed due to previous errors
- Removing TilesContext for context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
Jul 27, 2011 11:14:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

It looks like the jar needs internet connection to start, please let me know how to start the server without internet connection. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an incompatibility between the DTD version of struts declared in struts-plugin.xml file and the Struts version you are using.

source : http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=238

Comment: Yes, I changed struts-plugin.xml inside the jar file from 2.1.7 to 2.1 (as declared in application's struts.xml file).

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have multiple versions of the struts jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder. Keep only the version you need and try.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting this dependency into the application container's library folder and test if this helps?

Answer (score 0):

It means it cannot find the dtd declared into a strut-plugin.xml 
I solved this problem editing the struts-plugin.xml inside the strust2-jquery-*.jars. Remove the trailing spaces after the dtd declaration. 
i.e. change this

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd  ">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You proabably will find the required dependencies to be maintained here

[Struts2 jQuery configuration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195045/struts2-jquery-configuration-issue/15090741#15090741)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.