# Struts2 jQuery configuration issue

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

In my webapp I am using struts2-jquery plugin.

```
Struts2 version - 2.3.7
struts.jquery.version - 3.5.0
```

For using jQuery with Struts I've used the following configurations -

In pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts.jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

In my JSP added the following tag:

```
 <sj:head  jqueryui="true"/>
```

And used an `autocompleter` widget like this:

```
<s:url var="supUrl" namespace="/ajax" action="suppliers"/>
 <sj:autocompleter
    id="supplierMap"
    name="echo"
     label="Handle a Map"
     href="%{supUrl}"
     list="supplierMap"/>
```

I get the following JavaScript error:

```
Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined
jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind(jQuery('#supplierMap_widget'),options_supplierMap_widget);
```

When I do *View Page Source* in the browser I see the following. Here the path for the JavaScript include is not the same as how it is packaged in struts2-jquery-plugin.jar.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.5.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.5.0"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    jQuery.struts2_jquery.version="3.5.0";
    jQuery.scriptPath = "/struts/";
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

    jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.ui.struts2.min.js");

});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you deploying your application as root inside your container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if you are using struts2jQuery plugin, you must have following filter-mapping of url pattern /*  in web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Rest should work fine :)

Comment: Don't you kind of need that even if you're not using the jquery plugin?

Comment: Nope, If I aint using jquery plugin, I can write filter mapping for url pattern *.action :)

Comment: Not true, the default S2 themes also require the * mapping unless you extract the static files.

Answer (score 0):

try removing any namespace you might have added in struts.xml, adjust your urls accordingly. See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain following version of jars in your lib. I think you won't face any problem

antlr-2.7.6.jar commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar commons-collections-3.2.jar commons-digester.jar commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar commons-io-2.4.jar

commons-lang-1.2.jar commons-logging-1.1.jar freemarker-2.3.16.jar javassist-3.7.ga.jar ognl-3.0.jar struts2-core-2.2.3.jar

xwork-core-2.2.1.jar
struts2-jquery-plugin-3.1.1.jar

struts2

```
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem has anything to do with any of the above answers.

As the error messages says, your problem is that jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui is undefined.

This is supplied as the code warns:

```
 jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.ui.struts2.min.js");
```

This file is not in your  tag. See the .ui. ???

What you have is:

```
 "/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.5.0"
```